# How to fetch a header value/ body json value from HttpClient interceptor

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

> My Angular version: **6.0.3** and using **HttpClient** module

Hello in below code I am trying to fetch `res.headers` and `res.body` to fetch for example:
`res.headers.status`, `res.body.id` if possible:

but whenever I try to log in the console. it generates errors.
using syntax `res['headers']`, `res['body']` can be printed in the console. but no further fetching possible.

HttpsInterceptor  Class:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";
//import { MessageService } from '../../message.service';

export class HttpsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {       

        const started = Date.now();
        let ok: string;        
        let res: any;

        console.log(req.headers.keys());
        // return next.handle(req);

        // clone request and replace 'http://' with 'https://' at the same time
        const secureReq = req.clone({
            url: req.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
        });
        // send the cloned, "secure" request to the next handler.
        return next.handle(secureReq).pipe(            
            tap(
                // Succeeds when there is a response; ignore other events
                (event) => { 
                    ok = event instanceof HttpResponse ? 'succeeded' : ''
                    res = event;
                    console.log("Response:", res);
/* NOT WORKING */                        console.log("res: headers", res.headers);
/* NOT WORKING */                        console.log("res: body", res.body); 
                },
                // Operation failed; error is an HttpErrorResponse
                error => ok = 'failed'),
            finalize(() => {
                const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
                const msg = `${req.method} "${req.urlWithParams}"
                   ${ok} in ${elapsed} ms.`;
                //this.messenger.add(msg);
                console.log(msg);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
Response: 
{…}
​
body: {…}
​​
address: "76, Shilpgram tenaments, Soma talav, Dabhoi ring road, Vadodara, Gujarati, India - 390001"
​​
email: "cust@ngapp.com"
​​
fullname: "Amit Shah"
​​
id: 1
​​
password: "cust1234"
​​
phone: "+91-123456789"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: {…}
​​
lazyInit: function lazyInit()
​​
lazyUpdate: null
​​
normalizedNames: Map(0)
​​
<prototype>: Object { has: has()
, get: get(), keys: keys()
, … }
​
ok: true
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
type: 4
​
url: "https://demo1601932.mockable.io/customer/get/1"
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: HttpResponse()
, clone: clone() }
```

Comment: Check this out: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: *it generates errors*: which errors? Why don't you post them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `next.handle(...)` returns `Observable<HttpEvent>`.

This `HttpEvent` is 5 types.

`type HttpEvent<T> = HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<T> | HttpProgressEvent | HttpUserEvent<T>;`

So, you've to read response header when it is the type of `HttpResponse`. I just added a `if` block in your code.

```
return next.handle(secureReq)
    .pipe(            
            tap((event) => { 
                   ok = event instanceof HttpResponse ? 'succeeded' : '';
                   if(ok) {
                     res = event;
                     console.log("Response:", res);
                     console.log("res: headers", res.headers);
                     console.log("res: body", res.body);
                   }
             })

        );
```

Comment: Exact answer, thanks. can you tell more about `res.headers.customHeader` is possible to fetch? if your answer is CORS settings then I know it :P